# react navbar change it to onmouseover instead of click

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I wanted to load react navbar submenu on mouseover instead of click.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

```
import { Nav,NavDropdown,Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav>
                        <NavDropdown title="Beneficiary" id="basic-nav-dropdown" className="Dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item  onClick={() => this.recordList('Approved List',this.state.approvedRecords)}>Approved</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item onClick={() => this.recordList('Rejected List',this.state.rejectedRecords)}>Rejected</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item onClick={() => this.recordList('Referred Back List',this.state.refBackRecords)}>Referback</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I played with it for a minute

so as I first suggested we would add a local const and a function for handling dropdown visibility

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleHover = () => {
    setVisible((prevVisible) => (prevVisible = !prevVisible));
  };
```

And then simply

```
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" onMouseEnter={handleHover}>
            <Nav>
              <NavDropdown
                title="Beneficiary"
                id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                className="Dropdown"
                show={visible}
              >
...
```

As I suspected you'll have to handle the mouseleave event as well, so far in my function

```
setVisible((prevVisible) => (prevVisible = !prevVisible));
```

we're toggling the visibility on mouseenter, but you get the gist :)
LMK if I can help any further, or if you come across a better solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It is working but if I am doing mouseover on any of the navigation items all the submenus are getting visible of all the menus... rather only that specific navigation item submenu should be visible

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that you have multiple dropdowns. Then you'll have to add something unique(like a key or an id) to each  Navbar.Collapse and pass it in to handleHover.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to their docs, that cannot be done out of the box..
You could add your own function to NavDropdown on Mouseenter.. Provided you're using react hooks it would be something like

```
const [isDropdownVisible, setDropdownVisible] = useState(false);

const handleHover = () => {
  setDropdownVisible(true)
}
```

Of course you'll have to set submenu to be `visible={isDropdownVisible}`
and then on a parent you could just say `onmouseenter={handleHover}`
You might have to handle onmouseleave as well, I'm not sure.
Hope this will be a valuable guideline :)
Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It is working but if I am doing mouseover on any of the navigation items all the submenus are getting visible of all the menus... rather only that specific navigation item submenu should be visible